# Does NDK provide support for message queues?

Tags: android-ndk, ipc, message-queue

I'm trying to build a shared library using android ndk. I get this error when I run ndk build

```
fatal error: 'mqueue.h' file not found
```

From what I understand on Googling the issue is that Android does provide support for certain POSIX or System V functionalities (like message queues).

So I would like to know if this is right? And if yes, what are my options - what changes can I make to my application to perhaps imitate a message queue?

(Im using android-ndk-r16b on a Ubuntu 14.04 PC)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, POSIX message queues are not supported on Android, as well as some other SysV IPC mechanisms. In brief it is because of possibility to cause unreclaimable resource leaks. This is true not only for bugged applications that "forgets" to release acquired IPC resources but for every ones. The reason is that Android intensively uses `kill(app_pid, SIGKILL)` to reclaim system resources from background processes to the new ones, just launched by user. As result application dies with no chance to perform teardown. Kernel is not able to release that IPC resources because they may be shared by other processes in unpredictable way (unlike file descriptors and virtual memory). Remember that Android runs mostly on resource-constrained hardware so some kind of such resource rearranging is inevitable.
More background is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/android-4.2.2_r1.2/docs/system/libc/SYSV-IPC.html). Old NDK packages contained this document but at some point it was removed.

Alternative ways for IPC on Android typically include [`Binder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Binder.html)-based solutions. In native code you may use [`ashmem`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/libcutils/ashmem-dev.cpp) that offers interface for shared memory segments. Latest platform versions expose public API to it, see `<android/sharedmem.h>`. But event for older platforms you may implement similar functionality by direct interaction with ashmem driver, see `libcutils` sources.

At the end you may still use pipes, UNIX-domain sockets, and probably named pipes (of course if underlying filesystem supports such inodes).

Comment: Thanks. I ended up implementing a ring buffer. Its not foolproof as I have to initialize the buffer with a large enough size  so that messages don't get overwritten. Thus not the best alternative but it works. Binders seemed pretty complicated. Will look into a better solution when I get the time